'Aya said I am going to pass the test no matter what.' or 'Aya said I will pass the test no matter what.'
What is the difference in meaning for the two sentences ?

Aya said, "I am going to pass the test no matter what."

and

Aya said, "I will pass the test no matter what."


This question is similar to: In-depth explanation of the difference between "will" and "going to"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There’s no difference between using am going to and will.
Aya said I’m going to (or will) pass the test no matter what.
